# XSLT using Substring-Before and Substring-After not formatting correctly when the searched value occurs twice in the string

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have the following address in my xml and need to format out to address, city, state/zip on the output text file:

[image]

I'm using XSLT 2.0
Here is the xslt transformation I'm using

```
<xsl:variable name="LF" select="'&#xa;'"/>
```

```
    <xsl:function name="placer:GetStreetAddress">
         <xsl:param name="addressString" as="xs:string"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="substring($addressString, 1, string-length(substring-    before($addressString,$LF)))"/>
     </xsl:function>
```

```
<xsl:function name="placer:GetCityStateZip">
       <xsl:param name="addressString" as="xs:string"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="substring($addressString, (string-length(substring-before($addressString,$LF))) + 5 + 1 )"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="placer:GetCity">
       <xsl:param name="addressString" as="xs:string"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(placer:GetCityStateZip($addressString),',')"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="placer:GetStateZip">
       <xsl:param name="addressString" as="xs:string"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(substring-after($addressString,', '), ' ', ''),  1,7)"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="placer:PadRight">
      <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:param name="padChar" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:param name="stringToPad"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(substring(string-join(($stringToPad, for $i in (1 to $length) return $padChar),''),1,$length))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

The address on the file is displaying as:   [JESSE ST'
'CHANDLERAZ85225](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5G8U.png)

Verified the file is formatted correctly when supplying hardcoded values to the substring

Comment: Figured out what the issue was.  I needed to change the variable from <xsl:variable name="LF" select="'&#xa;'"/> to <xsl:variable name="LF" select="'&amp;#xa;'"/>.   This was then recognized in the substring logic.